# Custom search in SQL with rank by columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, search, full-text-search

I would like to implement intelligent search form for my users stored in SQL Server. Columns which I want to use for search are show on screenshot below.

[image]

But some columns have higher priority. For example if email or phone match with item in DB it will have higher rank then for example founded item by street and city.

I don't even know where to start.

I need just some hint what to study.

My application run under MVC 5 and for db I'm using SQL Server.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so implement your priority algorithm in sort order:

```
...
set @email = NullIf(@email, '')
set @city_id = NullIf(@city_id, 0)

SELECT
...
WHERE (@email is NULL or t.email = @email)
  AND (@city_id is NULL or t.city_id = @city_id)
  AND ...
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN @email = u.email THEN 1
    WHEN @city_id = t.city_id THEN 2
    ...
  END
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

`recompile` - to optimize search (execution plan) for different conditions.

Comment: This works but it returns also items which not match. Not sure how to use here "where" keyword

Comment: Mega - it works - thank you. Could you please help me one more time with punctuation. In "WHERE" clause I'm using "LIKE" instead of "=" ....

WHERE (@firstName is NULL or t.FirstName Like @firstName )

One of my row in column FirstName contains word "Ján". 
"Like" is working ok with small letter "j". But "á" is the problem if I tried search for example "ja%" it doesn't work. Do you have any tips how to solve it? thx

Comment: not sure, probably you have to surround your variable with %: `set @firstName = '%' + @firstName + '%'`